# How can I make boids move along a path?

Tags: particles, force-fields

I'm making a flock of birds with boids.  I want them to move along a path.

I tried curve guide, but they always move away from the curve.  If I make the particles Newtonian, then they follow the curve, but not boids. I want to use boids because I need them to be separate and flock reaching a goal.

Answer (score 4):

Have an empty follow the curve.

For the boids set your empty as goal.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could have them follow a "leader". You could create an Empty and have them follow that.  Your Empty could follow the curve.  "Follow Leader" is one of the rules in the Boid Brain section.

Comment: Where do you find and set these rules for boids? What is the complete list?