# How to randomize particle effects along a curve guide?

Tags: particles

I have set a curve guide as the Effector Group of my particle flow. Now, the particles move along a linear path, I want some of them to take a more random path -- like some of them follow the path but then slowly deviate away from it -- so that it seems less obvious. Is there any way I can do that?

This is my setup:
[image]

Comment: try reducing the influence of the curve guide and increasing the Brownian motion (random movement) of the particles.

Comment: @3pointedit i'll try that

Comment: @3pointedit hey, thanks that worked, but is there any way to restrict the brownian motion to the Z-axis?

Comment: Don't think so, as its a genuinely random motion. Perhaps instead you could move them through a field effect like turbulence or texture?

Comment: @3pointedit ok, i had it sorted out, not the according to the question I asked, but thanks anyways

Comment: IF you had an alternate solution why not post that as another question/answer so that others can learn ;-) You're allowed to answer your won questions here.

Comment: @3pointedit good idea

Comment: You can try using boids. have an empty follow the path and have the empty be the leader or goal for the boids. See: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33059/how-can-i-make-boids-move-along-a-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i experimented with my project, I couldn't find a definite solution. However,I was able to bypass the problem. I aligned the normals of the emitter along one of the axis, then with required level Brownian Motion set, I increased the Normal velocity of the particle system. Later I baked the Particle System, however this step was of my preference.
Similar results can also be achieved by setting a Particle System with the necessary -- Brownian Motion and Normal Velocity -- settings along with a Force Field of negative strength. **Note** that both the Particle System and Force Field have to exist on the same Layer. Also, a Force Field affects all particle systems present on the layer. Therefore, while using multiple particle systems place each of them on a different Layer if you don't want the Force Field affect them too.