# I want to animate a whole bunch of birds

Tags: animation

I’ve made a whole bunch of birds and I want to animate them.

The easiest way that I can think to do is put stage one down, next frame replace it with the second one and so on so forth.

But how would I do this? How do I go to the next frame and replace it without messing up frame number one?

Comment: Or if someone could just point me to a tutorial? That would be great

Comment: Maybe try particle system? Boids sounds like the correct mode. It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve, maybe you should do some research about it.

Comment: Do a search for boids. See this related answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33059/how-can-i-make-boids-move-along-a-path/42126#42126

Comment: I have no clue what that means